# Laravel - Routes - Differentiate subdomains from domain

Tags: routes, laravel-5.4

I'm using `Laravel 5.4`. My route is defined as below and uses a custom `middleware`.

#### web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'validCity'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@home')->name('home');
});
```

#### Situation

If I type `paris.example.com` I will be redirect to `HomeController@home`.

If I type `newyork.example.com` I will be redirect to `HomeController@home`.

If I type `example.com` I will also be redirect to `HomeController@home`.

#### Questions

Is that normal taking into account my `routes` definition ?

How can I make a different route depending on the presence of a `subdomain`

#### Example

If I type `example.com` I would like to be redirected to `view('Select Your Cities')` otherwise I would like to be redirect to `home`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### web.php

`Route::get('/', 'HomeController@home');`

#### HomeController.php

```
 public function home(Request $request)
    {
        $url_array = explode('.', parse_url($request->url(), PHP_URL_HOST));
        $subdomain = $url_array[0];
        $subdomain = strtolower($subdomain);
        $subdomain = str_replace(' ', '', $subdomain);

        $city = City::where(DB::raw('lower(replace(name, \' \', \'\'))'),'LIKE', $subdomain)->get();

        if($city->isEmpty()) {
            return view('empty');
        }
        return view('app');
    }
```